# How can I enable a function which prints all the items in an Excel Web Part?

Tags: printing, chart-web-part, chart, excel-web-access-webpart

I want to be able to print all the charts from the drop down list. As it is now, I am only available to choose one chart/named item, print it, change item, print and so on.

[image: Example of how it looks like]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

- Click File, and then click Print.
- Under Settings, click the arrow next to Print Active Sheets and select the appropriate option.

[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you for answering,

Maybe I was a little bit vauge, but I meant when I am on the SharePoint page where the Excel charts are displayed I want to be able to print all the charts/items in that web part instead of doing it one by one.